# Nondeterministic behavior and output behavior In Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0

I am having an issue with thus piece of code I wrote to perform a custom operation in Tensorflow ( 2.3 ) . The code generally works fine but sometimes throws unexpected errors and exceptions even through it worked fine in other executions with the same inputs.

I have tried to troubleshoot the issue and I'm almost convinced that it is an evaluation dependency issue. I tried to added some dependencies controls but that did not work. Apologies for the little bit lengthy code by I really could not reproduce the issue in a smaller example. Below is my code :

```
  import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
tf.disable_v2_behavior()


myTensor_values = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
myTensor_l2_splits = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)
myTensor_l1_splits = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)


def innerloop_processing(begin_index , end_index , input1) : 
    innerloop_counter = begin_index
    ta = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True, clear_after_read=False , infer_shape=False )
    def innerloop_body(counter , begin_index , end_index , input1 , ta) : 
        inner_being_index = input1[1][counter]
        inner_end_index = input1[1][counter+1]
        row = tf.slice(input1[0] , [inner_being_index] ,  [inner_end_index-inner_being_index])
        ta = ta.write(counter-begin_index , row)
        counter = counter + 1 
        return counter , begin_index , end_index , input1 , ta
    
    
    def innerloop_cond(counter , begin_index , end_index , input1 , ta ) : 
        return input1[1][counter] < input1[1][end_index] -1  #stop at the next pointer of the l2_splits 
 
    results = tf.while_loop(innerloop_cond , innerloop_body , [innerloop_counter , begin_index , end_index , input1 , ta] )
    print_resutls = tf.print("this is the component result  :" , results[4].stack())
    return results[4].stack()


def generateL1Tensor_writeback(start_offest,step,num):
    counter=tf.constant(0,tf.int32)
    values = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True, clear_after_read=False , infer_shape=False )
    def cond(values , start_offest , num ,counter) : 
        return counter*step <= num*step
    def body(values , start_offest , num ,counter) : 
        values = values.write(counter,[(counter*step)+start_offest])
        counter = counter+1
        return  values , start_offest , num ,counter
    
    final_values , _ , _ , _  = tf.while_loop(cond,body,[values , start_offest , num , counter])
    final = final_values.concat()
    #print_line = tf.print(" xxxxx This is the is the split : " ,  final)
    return final

def multiply2n_ragged(tensor1 , tensor2) : 
    #this  function multiplies two ragged tesnsors of rank 2 . the most outer ranks of the two tensros must be equal .
    #setting variables and constats 
    outerloop_counter = tf.constant(0 , dtype=tf.int32)
    carry_on = tf.constant(0 , dtype=tf.int32)
    taValues = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True, clear_after_read=False , infer_shape=False )
    taL2Splits = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True, clear_after_read=False , infer_shape=False )
    taL1Splits = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True, clear_after_read=False , infer_shape=False )
    taL1Splits = taL1Splits.write(0,[0]) ## required intialization for L1 split only
    innerloop_processing_graphed = tf.function(innerloop_processing)
    generateL1Tensor_writeback_graphed = tf.function(generateL1Tensor_writeback)
    def outerloop_cond(counter,input1,input2 ,taValues  ,taL2Splits , taL1Splits , carry_on ) :
        value = tf.shape(input1[2])[0]-1
        return counter < value ## this is the length of the outermost dimision , stop of this 
    def outloop_body(counter,input1,input2, taValues  ,taL2Splits , taL1Splits , carry_on) : 
        l1_comp_begin = input1[2][counter]                  ## this is begin position of the current row in the outer split  ( ie. the ith value in the outer row split tensor ) 
        l1_comp_end = input1[2][counter+1]                  ## this is end position of the current row in the outer split   (ie. the ith + 1 value in the outer row split tensor)
        l1_comp2_begin = input2[2][counter]                 ## we do the same for the second components 
        l1_comp2_end = input2[2][counter+1]                 ## we do the same for the second components
        comp  = innerloop_processing_graphed(l1_comp_begin ,l1_comp_end ,input1  ) ## now retrive the data to be procesed for the selected rows from vector1
        comp2  =innerloop_processing_graphed(l1_comp2_begin ,l1_comp2_end ,input2  ) ## do the same for vector 2 
        
        comp2 = tf.transpose(comp2) ### desired operation
        multiply =tf.matmul(comp , comp2) #### This is the desired operation  

        
        myshape= tf.shape(multiply) ## calculate the shape of the result in order to prepare to write the result in a ragged tensor format. 
        offset = tf.cond( taValues.size() >0  ,lambda: tf.shape(taValues.concat())[0] , lambda : [0]) ### this is a hack, TensorArray.concat returns an error if the array is empty. Thus we check before calling this. 
        l2v = generateL1Tensor_writeback_graphed(offset,myshape[1],myshape[0])  # generate the inner row split of the result for the current element
        taL2Splits=taL2Splits.write(counter,l2v) # write back the inner rowlplit to a TensorArray 
        taValues=taValues.write(counter,tf.reshape(multiply , [-1])) # wirte back the actual ragged tensor elemnts in a another TensorArray
        carry_on=carry_on+myshape[0] ## required to calculate the outer row splite
        taL1Splits=taL1Splits.write(counter+1,[carry_on]) ## This is the outmost row split. 
        counter = counter+1
        return counter , input1,input2, taValues  ,taL2Splits , taL1Splits , carry_on
    
    outerloop_finalcounter , _ , _ , ta1,ta2,ta3,_ = tf.while_loop(outerloop_cond,outloop_body,[outerloop_counter , tensor1 , tensor2 ,taValues  ,taL2Splits , taL1Splits,carry_on])
    uinquie_ta2 , _ = tf.unique(ta2.concat())  # this is required since some values might be duplicate in the row split itself 
    final_values = ta1.concat() , uinquie_ta2   ,ta3.concat()
    return final_values




t = myTensor_values , myTensor_l2_splits , myTensor_l1_splits

oo   =multiply2n_ragged(t,t)
new_oo = multiply2n_ragged(oo,oo)


sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)))
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
vals =np.array([1.0, 2.2  , 1.1 , 4.0, 5.0 , 1.1 , 6.0, 7.0 , 1.1 , 8.0, 9.0 , 1.1 ,10.0, 11.0 , 1.1 ])
l2_splits = np.array([0,3,6,9,12,15])
l1_splits = np.array([0, 2, 5  ]) 
re       = sess.run([new_oo  ] , feed_dict={myTensor_values:vals ,myTensor_l1_splits:l1_splits ,myTensor_l2_splits:l2_splits  } )
print(re)
```

As I said the code works fine many times , however it some times generates the below errors for the same inputs . stack traces of the some of different errors that I get :

```
this is the component result  : [[1 2.2 1.1]
 [4 5 1.1]]
this is the component result  : [[1 2.2 1.1]
 [4 5 1.1]]
this is the component result  : [[6 7 1.1]
 [8 9 1.1]
 [10 11 1.1]]
this is the component result  : [[6 7 1.1]
 [8 9 1.1]
 [10 11 1.1]]
this is the component result  : [[7.05 16.21]
 [16.21 42.21]]
this is the component result  : [[7.05 16.21]
 [16.21 42.21]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\AutoEncoder\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1364     try:
-> 1365       return fn(*args)
   1366     except errors.OpError as e:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\AutoEncoder\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1349       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1350                                       target_list, run_metadata)
   1351 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\AutoEncoder\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1442                                             fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1443                                             run_metadata)
   1444 

InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __inference_innerloop_processing_13658}} {{function_node __inference_innerloop_processing_13658}} Expected size[0] in [0, 0], but got 3
     [[{{node while/body/_1/while/Slice}}]]
     [[while_33/StatefulPartitionedCall_1]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-238a2ce9a03a> in <module>
     94 l2_splits = np.array([0,3,6,9,12,15])
     95 l1_splits = np.array([0, 2, 5  ])
---> 96 re       = sess.run([new_oo  ] , feed_dict={myTensor_values:vals ,myTensor_l1_splits:l1_splits ,myTensor_l2_splits:l2_splits  } )
     97 print(re)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\AutoEncoder\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    956     try:
    957       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 958                          run_metadata_ptr)
    959       if run_metadata:
    960         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\AutoEncoder\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1179     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1180       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1181                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1182     else:
   1183       results = []

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\AutoEncoder\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1357     if handle is None:
   1358       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1359                            run_metadata)
   1360     else:
   1361       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\AutoEncoder\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1382                     '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.'
   1383                     'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
-> 1384       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1385 
   1386   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError:   Expected size[0] in [0, 0], but got 3
     [[{{node while/body/_1/while/Slice}}]]
     [[while_33/StatefulPartitionedCall_1]]
```

and the below error as well :

```
CancelledError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\AutoEncoder\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1364     try:
-> 1365       return fn(*args)
   1366     except errors.OpError as e:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\AutoEncoder\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1349       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1350                                       target_list, run_metadata)
   1351 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\AutoEncoder\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1442                                             fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1443                                             run_metadata)
   1444 

CancelledError: {{function_node __inference_innerloop_processing_11240}} {{function_node __inference_innerloop_processing_11240}} [_Derived_]Loop execution was cancelled.
     [[{{node while/LoopCond/_20}}]]
     [[while_27/StatefulPartitionedCall_1]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

CancelledError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-238a2ce9a03a> in <module>
     94 l2_splits = np.array([0,3,6,9,12,15])
     95 l1_splits = np.array([0, 2, 5  ])
---> 96 re       = sess.run([new_oo  ] , feed_dict={myTensor_values:vals ,myTensor_l1_splits:l1_splits ,myTensor_l2_splits:l2_splits  } )
     97 print(re)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\AutoEncoder\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    956     try:
    957       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 958                          run_metadata_ptr)
    959       if run_metadata:
    960         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\AutoEncoder\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1179     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1180       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1181                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1182     else:
   1183       results = []

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\AutoEncoder\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1357     if handle is None:
   1358       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1359                            run_metadata)
   1360     else:
   1361       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\AutoEncoder\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1382                     '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.'
   1383                     'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
-> 1384       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1385 
   1386   def _extend_graph(self):

CancelledError:   [_Derived_]Loop execution was cancelled.
     [[{{node while/LoopCond/_20}}]]
     [[while_27/StatefulPartitionedCall_1]]
```

I believe all errors are thrown inside `innerloop_processing`. I have also opened an issue in Tensorflow github [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42594) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the issue was from tf.Cond and this was fortunately is was reimplemented in tensorflow2. Thus  removing the call :

```
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

fixes the issue.